# Gulp Angular File Sort Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

So when I have the `.pipe(angularFilesort())` in my gulp script, after I run `gulp` it executes `wiredep`, but never gets into the `default` task, and just stops.  If I remove `.pipe(angularFilesort())` it the script runs perfectly fine.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true});
var angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');

function startBrowserSync() {
    if (browserSync.active) {
        console.log("already running");
        return;
}
    var options = {
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
        files: [config.js]
    }
    browserSync.init(options);
}

gulp.task('default', ['wiredep'], function () {
    startBrowserSync();
    gulp.watch(config.js, browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(config.html, browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

    return gulp
        .src(config.index)
        .pipe(wiredep(options))
        .pipe($.inject(
            gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js']).pipe(angularFilesort())
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick, it looks OK to me. Because you are using *gulp-load-plugins* and you don't need to require gulp-inject it is hard to see if inject is properly installed.

You say that it works without `angularFilesort()`.

Likewise, use gulp-load-plugins to load gulp-angular-filesort. The second dash and every dash thereafter are turned into camel case by gulp-load-plugins.

Try: `pipe($.angularFilesort())`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it was actually because I had been converting this small project from react w/es6 to angular.  I had commented out all the react files, but then I uncommented one of my files, and when I recommented it out, it started working.